# how to print only the file name

Tags: c, string, file, fopen, fgets

I am reading in a archive file. A archive file created using `ar` command in unix. When I put the file it says this

```
!<arch>
correct.c/      1319871022  1000  1000  100664  0         `
hello.c/        1319871007  1000  1000  100664  0         `
hi.c/           1319870999  1000  1000  100664  0         `
make.c/         1319871028  1000  1000  100664  0         `
pie.c/          1319871015  1000  1000  100664  0         `
three.c/        1319871035  1000  1000  100664  0         `
```

What I want to display is just

```
correct.c
hello.c
hi.c
make.c
pie.c
three.c
```

Here is the code concerning this part. `archive_name` is the filename. `filestr` is string that can hold up too 30 `chars` and file is a `FILE *file` but its declared above.

```
file = fopen(archive_name, "r");
if(file == NULL) perror("\nError opening file\n");
else {
    while( fgets(filestr, 10, file) != NULL )
        printf("%s", filestr);

fclose(file);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `correct.c/`, `hello.c/`, etc. contents in the archive? Or are they actual files opened by the program?
I've never encountered `ar` or these types of archives before.

Comment: Hey are contents of the archive

Answer (score 0):

As you've already seen, an archive starts with "!" (followed by a new-line).

After that, you have a struct roughly like this:

```
#pragma pack(1) // use whatever your compiler wants to ensure against padding.
struct file_header { 
    char filename[16];
    char timestamp[11];
    char ownerID[5];
    char groupID[5];
    char filemode[8];
    char filesize[9];
    char magic[2];
};
```

There's one of this for each file in the archive, so if you want to dump just filenames, you can (at least on theory -- keep reading) skip the header, then read through these and display the file names.

That does have one problem though: as you can see, it allows only 16 bytes for each file name, which often isn't sufficient. There are various ways of handling this, and (unfortunately) they vary from one implementation of `ar` to the next, so it's next to impossible to tell you how to get the real file names.

Probably the most obvious solution would be to use `popen` to run `ar` (and hope that it matches the format of the archive files you need to look at).

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am still learning C so almost everything is still quite new to me. When I use fgets, it reads in the line correct? Does everything just fall into that struct? Or how would I use this struct? cause I would like to do a verbose way of listing the files as well. I hope I just made sense, I've been coding for a good 10 hours now lol.

Comment: Sorry about the misname. I meant Jerry. Totally sorry.

Comment: @inoobdotcom: when you want to read data into a struct, you usually use `fread`, as in `fread(&mystruct, sizeof(struct), 1, my_file);`.